# How can I parse a seemingly standard Timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, android, date

Very simple task. I want to reformat a timestamp sent to me from a service with the format of *Wed, 26 Jan 2011 22:27:09 +0000*.

```
String format = "EEEE; MMMM d, yyyy";
String timestamp = "Wed, 26 Jan 2011 22:27:09 +0000";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(timestamp);
Log.d("Test", date.toString());
```

I haven't been able to find what formats `.parse()` method will allow but this one throws a `ParseException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
String format = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z";
```

When I use that [format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your test string, I get (in Central Time):

```
Wed Jan 26 16:27:09 CST 2011
```

Comment: Seems like it wasn't happy about the ";" in my format. Too much PHP for me, I guess. Any idea how to escape that in a string literal so I can have "Tuesday; January"?

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm stupid. I thought that parse() would parse any date based string into the format I wanted, not that it needed to *use* that format. I thought it was like php's strtotime(). Thanks!

Comment: @typeonerror - Try surrounding the `;` with single quotes, that's the typical way to escape non-format characters. To have "Tuesday, January", try `EEEE';' MMMM`